# Popup slide up from the bottom overflowing other div blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make a popup slide up when clicking on the link.
I've prepared an example with elements around the popup under this [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/12nnzmz9/)

There are 2 blocks (block and footer}:

```
<div id="block">
  Some content inside the block.
</div>

<div id="Popup">
  <div class="Container">
    <div id="tmp"> Popup!
      <span id="close">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <span id="FooterLink">Link</span>
</div>
```

Between them as you can see there is my hidden popup, which I would like to show just above the footer block. When pressing a link in in the footer area, the popup should slowly slide up above the footer overflowing the block above the footer. My popup should have dynamic height because of different content inside depending of a language is chosen by the user. Sorry for my english, hopefully someone can help me with this. I found an example here [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8LXY6/) how should this work (except the clients button is my footer and I can have only popup with absolute position or z-index so I can't really use this example).

The rest of the code:
CSS:

```
#block {
  height: 150px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #505050;
  text-align: center;
}

#Popup {
  display: none;
  position:absolute; 
  z-index: 100; 
  background-color: red; 
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
}
#close {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#FooterLink {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
 $('#FooterLink').click(function () {
    $('#Popup').slideToggle();
 });
 $('#close').click(function () {
    $('#Popup').slideToggle();
 });
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/jitendratiwari/12nnzmz9/1/

Comment: thx, but no. It should come up above the blue area (above footer).

Comment: see my complete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many ways you could accomplish this. What I did was to wrap your `footer` and `popup` elements under one wrapping `div`. This helps in placing and animating their positions in relation to each other. I also wrapped the entire box in one div and called it `box`.

The `footer-container` is given a height equal to the and `footer` element. When you click on the button, `bottom` with the value of the element's height is applied and since the `popup` is positioned absolutely, it will animate upwards.

Removing `bottom: 60px` hides the element again.

This implementation allows for a dynamic height of the `popup` element as well.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/12nnzmz9/5/)

```js
 $('#FooterLink').click(function() {
   $('#Popup').animate({
     top: -$("#Popup").height()
   });
 });
 $('#close').click(function() {
   $('#Popup').animate({
     top: 0
   });
 });
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
}
#block {
  height: 150px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #505050;
  text-align: center;
}
#Popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
}
#close {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#footer-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}
#footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#FooterLink {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  Some content inside the block.
</div>
<div id="footer-container">
  <div id="Popup">
    <div class="Container">
      <div id="tmp">Popup!
        <span id="close">X</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <span id="FooterLink">Link</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was expecting. I adopted your solution to my real code and it seems to be working fine :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: I found one thing not working well with this solution and I can't fix it. I just changed two things in css style for `#Popup {min-height: 160px}` so it's bigger then the footer container and `#block {height: 900px}`. Here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12nnzmz9/11/) for code, but it's not possible to test it. The problem is when I try to link to the footer like `http://myweb.com/index.php#footer` or anywhere else on the page the popup shows behind and partly below the footer (without clicking the link). I hope you can still help with this.

Comment: can you link to your project or a fiddle that shows this? I cannot help if I cannot test it.

Comment: Here is the link do [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12nnzmz9/12/). I added a link on top of it "Go to footer" and this bad effect is the same as it was passed with domain and hash. Hope you can help with the fix.

Comment: I think I've finally fixed this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12nnzmz9/13/) and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You simple need to change you css `#Popup` position to `relative`

Try this solution

```js
 $('#FooterLink').click(function () {
    $('#Popup').show(2000);
 });
 $('#close').click(function () {
    $('#Popup').hide(2000);
 });
```

```css
#block {
  height: 150px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #505050;
  text-align: center;
}

#Popup {
  display: none;
  position:relative; 
  z-index: 100; 
  background-color: red; 
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
}
#close {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#FooterLink {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
    Some content inside the block.
  </div>
  
  <div id="Popup">
  <div class="Container">
    <div id="tmp"> Popup!
          <span id="close">X</span>
        </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div id="footer">
    <span id="FooterLink">Link</span>
  </div>
```